# Mapstruct mappers diamond inheritance, method is already defined

Tags: java, inheritance, java-11, mapstruct

I have following situation, I simplified my actual case and I created minimum example showing my case:

[image]

Two empty, not relevant in this example, classess `Phone` and `PhoneDto`, and mappers inheritance structure, `TestSuperMapper` with one method declaration to map `PhoneDto` to `Phone`, two empty interfaces `TestParent1Mapper` and `TestParent2Mapper` both extending `TestSuperMapper`, one actual mapper interface `TestMapper` annotated with `@Mapper` extending both `TestParent1Mapper` and `TestParent2Mapper`, and `TestMapperImpl` class implementing `TestMapper` generated by mapstruct. Problem with this setup is that mapstruct generates `TestMapperImpl` with following content:

```
import javax.annotation.processing.Generated;

@Generated(...)
public class TestMapperImpl implements TestMapper {

    @Override
    public Phone map(PhoneDto phoneDto) {
        if ( phoneDto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Phone phone = new Phone();

        return phone;
    }

    @Override
    public Phone map(PhoneDto phoneDto) {
        if ( phoneDto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Phone phone = new Phone();

        return phone;
    }
}
```

So it won't comple, as method `Phone map(PhoneDto)` is declared twice, one is coming via `TestParent1Mapper` inheritance path, second via `TestParent2Mapper`. Is there possibility to avoid such situation without altering my inheritance structure? Mapstruct version 1.4.1.Final, jdk 11. Actual javac exception is `java: method map(PhoneDto) is already defined in class TestMapperImpl.`

Comment: Looks like a bug in MapStruct (that resembles the [deadly diamond of death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem)). Best ask for advice / open a bug report through by creating a ticket int the [github project](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it is mapstruct issue, I've created and issue and maintainers of mapstruct fixed it already: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2437